# Mod_Rewrite + AJAX Posts Doesn't Work Well With Each Other?

Tags: jquery

I have a system which uses mod_rewrite, making these URLs `/index.php?page=login` into `/login/`.

When I post the classic way `action="/login/"` and I'm done without any problems(the GET parameter tells index.php to let the login module to process the POST data).

However when I use jQuery's post function `$.post("/login/",...)` instead, it won't work correctly. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What do server logs say?  Did you look at the good and bad sequence with something like Live HTTP Headers and/or Firebug?  Does the jQuery POST work with /index.php?page=login?

Comment: Could you post your `.htaccess` code?

Answer (score 1):

So your jquery post looks something like this:

```
$.post('YOURPHPFILE.php', function(data) {
   ...and so on
});
```

replace it with

```
$.post('../YOURPHPFILE.php', function(data) {
  ...and so on
});
```

this "../" should fix it, as your jquery post simply can't locate your php file.